# Different version of MediaWiki on the same server

Tags: php, mediawiki

From what I can tell, people install multiple instances of MediaWiki on the same server all the time.  However, I am not sure if you can install different versions of MediaWiki on the same server.  Basically, I have a host running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard with two wikis using MediaWiki (1.17.0) and PHP (5.3.6).  I want to create a new wiki with the latest version of MediaWiki, which means I would probably have to install a more current version of PHP.  Will the different versions of MediaWiki be able to coexist in harmony?  Oddly enough, I have been prowling the internet and cannot seem to find a straight answer.

Comment: Your question asks if you can run multiple versions of MediaWiki on the same server.  But you're already doing that, no?

Comment: The two wikis that are on the server are the same version (1.17.0).  Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: According to the docs, MediaWiki 1.25.2 requests PHP 5.3.5+, so I probably will not have to install a new version of PHP.  Makes life a little easier.

Comment: No.  I misunderstood.  Apologies

Comment: No worries!  Thanks for your response!

Comment: @ChristopherSpears, indeed PHP or DB incompatibility would be the only show stopper: you can post your comment as own answer. However, 5.3.x won't be supported for much longer. What is stopping you from upgrading the other wiki?